# JS will not change the navigation display property from none to flex

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

JS will not change the nav-hidden display property from none to flex. I tried with !important, that seems to work in some cases, but I would like to know why this does not work, so that I can understand this better.
When I press the button there is a new class assigned to the element, but the property stays as none.

What I was trying to do: have nav-hidden only appear when I click on button over the whole screen when the screen is smaller than 700px, and have nav-line in line with the logo inside when screen is wider than 700px.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var fullnavigation = document.getElementById("nav-hidden");
    fullnavigation.classList.toggle("open-nav");
}
```

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
header{
    background-color: #009933;
    width:100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
}
.logo img{
    display: block;
    height: 4em;
}
@media screen and (max-width:700px){
    .nav-line{
        display: none;
    }
    .open-nav{
        display: flex;    
    }
    .nav-hidden{
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #009933;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .nav-button{
        display: block;
        color: #ffffff;
        background-color: transparent;
        padding: 0px;
        border: 0px;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 4em;
        z-index: 9999;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sl">
<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" href="slike\favicon\favicon.png" type="image/gif" size="128x128">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="js\index.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css\index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="logo"><img src="" alt="logo"></div>
        <button id="nav-button" onclick="myFunction()">☰</button>
        <nav id="nav-line" class="nav-line">
                <div class="nav-text"><a href="#">DOMOV</a></div>
                <div class="nav-text"><a href="#">O NAS</a></div>
                <div class="nav-text"><a href="#">KONTAKT</a></div>
                <div class="nav-text"><a href="#">POVPRAŠEVANJE</a></div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <nav id="nav-hidden" class="nav-hidden">
        <div class="nav-text"><a href="#">DOMOV</a></div>
        <div class="nav-text"><a href="#">O NAS</a></div>
        <div class="nav-text"><a href="#">KONTAKT</a></div>
        <div class="nav-text"><a href="#">POVPRAŠEVANJE</a></div>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As CSS reads your code successively, `.open-nav` class has been intercepted by the next one `.nav-hidden`. Problem is not in your JS code and if you look to this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k7qrLawj/) it works and js switches your class well. Just put `.open-nav` after `.nav-hidden`

```
@media screen and (max-width:700px){
    .nav-line{
        display: none;
    }
    .nav-hidden{
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #009933;
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .open-nav{
        display: flex;    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`.classList.toggle('className')` : When only one argument is present: Toggle the class value; i.e., if the class exists then remove it and return false, if not, then add it and return true.

So your JS will add the "open-nav" class but won't remove the "hidden-nav". I think the error might come from that.

Tell me if you need more help after that.

**Source:**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList